# Do cubics always have one real root?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers

I've seen a few conflicting pieces of information online.

So far, I know that with real coefficients there will always be one real root. But how about with complex coefficients?

At very least could you give me a counterexample? A cubic with no real roots.

Comment: It's more clear to say "at least one real root" or "a real root". There are real cubics that have three real roots (there are none that have exactly two though).

Comment: @quid: If you count with multiplicity, that's true. If you don't, then you can have $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)^2$.

Comment: Indeed @Kevin I should have made that explicity.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One of the best things you can remember is that over a field (like the reals or complex numbers) roots come from linear factors.  Use this to build your own examples:  $f(z) =(z-i)^3$.  If you want three distinct complex roots, do something like $f(z) = (z-i)(z+i)(z-2i)$.

Answer (score 18):

As you already know, a cubic with real coefficients always has at least one real root, so there is no counterexample of a cubic with real coefficients with no real roots.

A cubic with complex coefficients with no real roots is easy to find; take $x^3+i$.

Comment: @Glen_b It is reasonable to say has one X to mean there exists an X, though it would be more clear to say there is at least one X.

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Over the complex numbers, every polynomial factors into roots. So we can take any cubic and write it as $a(x-u)(x-v)(x-w)$ where $u, v, w$ are the roots (they don't need to be distict) and $a$ is the leading coefficient. This lets us form polynomials with only complex roots such as $(x-i)^3$.

However, if all the original coefficients of the polynomial are real, and $c$ is a complex root, then its conjugate $\bar{c}$ must also be a root: complex roots to polynomials with real coeffecients must come in pairs. This is called the [complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

This means that a polynomial with real coefficients and odd degree will always have at least one real root, which answers the case for cubics. A quadratic with negative discriminant on the other hand has two, conjugate complex roots.